# Objective C: several categories on one class

Tags: ios, objective-c, categories

I must have misunderstood `Categories` I made a category on a class to extend it with some methods, and make some methods abstract following the OOP guidelines. But I thought that only when I `#import` and use the category will those methods in the category be called. Instead I find when I `#import` and use the base class, that this class will automatically call that method but in the Category on the class, not itself.

What I wanted was if the user tried to use this method in the class without a category a exception would get trowed. And this way I could make different categories on the same class
with slightly different internal behavior.

Am I just misunderstanding Categories ?

Answer (score 1):

Categories add methods to a class without condition or other means of picking and choosing.

Once the methods are added to the class, there is no removal short of mucking with the runtime directly.

Subclasses inherit the additional methods.

It doesn't matter if you `#import` the method declarations or not.

If you want different versions of a class, declare different subclasses.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't matter if you #import the method declarations? Are you saying that if you create a category on a class, you can use those methods without importing the category's .h file?

Comment: At runtime, the class's own methods and the methods added to the class by the category are indistinguishable. Anybody can call the methods added by the category with no runtime error. The difference is at compile time: if you try to call the category's methods without importing the category header, you'll get a compiler warning.